# how is the 'response' parameter calculated for rtsp authentication?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

So I've captured a couple of packets from ffmpeg to a ip camera with rtsp, which I've attached at the end of the question:

In the second request/response pair, the protocol sees that it needs authentication and returns a `nonce="be129bc71fa3ddfbff9989ed6f748268"` to the user

In the third request/response pair, there is a `response="da0882d360a56deef2994d8ba0de8e89"` being sent to the server and I'm not sure how that is generated. The user/password pair is `admin` with a blank password.

Any ideas of where to look in the RFCs would be great

---

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.245:88/videoMain RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: Lavf56.4.101

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Date: Sun, Sep 21 2014 01:33:07 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, GET_PARAMETER, SET_PARAMETER

----------

DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.245:88/videoMain RTSP/1.0
Accept: application/sdp
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Lavf56.4.101

RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
CSeq: 2
Date: Sun, Sep 21 2014 01:33:07 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="LIVE555 Streaming Media", nonce="be129bc71fa3ddfbff9989ed6f748268"

----------

DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.245:88/videoMain RTSP/1.0
Accept: application/sdp
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: Lavf56.4.101
Authorization: Digest username="admin",realm="LIVE555 Streaming Media",nonce="be129bc71fa3ddfbff9989ed6f748268",uri="rtsp://192.168.1.245:88/videoMain",response="da0882d360a56deef2994d8ba0de8e89"


RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Sun, Sep 21 2014 01:33:07 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.245:65534/videoMain/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 500

v=0
o=- 1411259869717503 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.245
s=IP Camera Video
i=videoMain
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.01.25
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:IP Camera Video
a=x-qt-text-inf:videoMain
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001F;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAH5WoFAFuQA==,aM48gA==
a=control:track1
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:64
a=control:track2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is converted by RFC 2617 "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication" - read the Digest part in this case.
http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt